# How finally block work

Tags: java

If `finally` block executes before `return statement present in side try block`, then why `return list` is not printing `null` instead printing [DEV].

```
public class Sub {
 List list = new ArrayList();

  public List check(){
    try {
        list.add("DEV");
        return list;
    }finally{
        list = null;    
                System.out.println("Inside finally ["+list+"]");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sub sup = new Sub();

    System.out.println(sup.check());
    System.out.println(sup.list);
  }
}
```

---

**O/P:**

- Inside finally [null]
- [DEV]
- null

Answer (score 0):

The value object referred by `list` is updated on the stack before `finally` statement is executed.
This is how it goes

- List item `return list;` in `try` block updates the object referred by `list` on stack.
- On the other hand, even if `finally` block is executed after `try` block, assignment `list = null;` is done but the value is not updated on the stack. It does not change the returned value.
- Statement `System.out.println(sup.check());` prints `DEV` because it is the value returned from `try` block i.e. which was updated on the stack.
- Here `System.out.println(sup.list);` you are directly referring to `list` variable which was set to `null` using `list = null;` in `finally` block which does not update the value on stack.

Answer (score -1):

Finally *doesnt* execute before return, it executes after it, when the return value of the method is already set.

I dont't know why people marked this down. I maintain that it is the simple correct answer. If we disregard the possibility of exceptions, an equivalent implementation of the `check()` method is:

```
public List check() {

    // try block part        
    list.add("DEV");
    List ret_val = list;

    // finally block part
    list = null;    
    System.out.println("Inside finally ["+list+"]");

    // and then actually exit the method
    return ret_val;
}
```

That is, `return` in the presence of a finally block does not mean “exit immediately”, but “set the pending return value, and exit when the finally block is done”.